# Eliminate duplicate profiles from XML file iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

I am creating an app that loads an XML file with a list of profiles from the web. There is a button that shows all the profiles in a textView when pressed.

Now I want to have another button to remove duplicate profiles from that list on the textView, any help on how to do that is appreciated!

**I have a:**

NSMutableDictionary *profileDict;

NSMutableArray *profile;

NSArray *profileArr;

I have researched on how to do it but couldn't find something that was related to what I need. I have read something about NSPredicate but I am new to it and don't know how to make it work on my project.

IBAction for removing the duplicates:

```
- (IBAction)removeDuplicates:(id)sender
{
    //How should I start here.....?
}
```

**ALL THE CLASSES TO SUPPORT THE QUESTIONS**

Underneath I have put the rest of the classes to make everything clear.

***XMLParser.h***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface XMLParser : NSObject

{
    bool isStatus;
    XMLParser *currentProfile;
    XMLParser *xmlParser;
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableString *currentNodeContent;
    NSMutableArray *profile;
    NSString *firstName;
}

- (void)loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString;
- (void)loadXML;

- (NSString *)firstName;

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *profileDict;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *profile;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *profileArr;

@end
```

***XMLParser.m***

```
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "Globals.h"

@implementation XMLParser
-(id)loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    self.profileDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    self.profile=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    self.profileArr=[[NSArray alloc]init];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dierenpensionlindehof.nl/profiles1.xml"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return self;
}


-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstname"])
    {
        currentProfile = [XMLParser alloc];
        isStatus = YES;
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"firstname"])
    {

        currentProfile->firstName = currentNodeContent;
    //    NSLog(@"%@",currentProfile->firstName);
        [self.profileDict setObject:currentProfile->firstName forKey:@"firstname"];
    }

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"profile"])
    {
        [self.profile addObject:self.profileDict];
        self.profileDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [[Globals globalBinding]setGlobalArr:self.profile];
    }
}

-(void)loadXML
{
    [self loadXMLByURL:@"http://dierenpensionlindehof.nl/profiles1.xml"];
}

-(NSString *)firstName
{
    return firstName;
}

@end
```

***ViewController.h***

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "XMLParser.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *profilesLabelTextView;

@end
```

***ViewController.m***

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "XMLParser.h"
#import "Globals.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
 - (IBAction)removeDuplicates:(id)sender
{
}

//Code for the button to display the profiles
- (IBAction)showProfilesButton:(id)sender
{
    XMLParser* parser = [[XMLParser alloc]init];
    [parser loadXML];

    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for(NSMutableDictionary *obj in [[Globals globalBinding]globalArr])
    {
        [str appendFormat:@"\n %@", [obj objectForKey:@"firstname"]];
    }

    [self.profilesLabelTextView setText:str];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

***Global.h***

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Globals : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *globalArr;
+(Globals*)globalBinding;

@end
```

***Global.m***

```
#import "Globals.h"
static Globals *global=nil;

@implementation Globals

+(Globals*)globalBinding
{
    if (global == nil) {
        global = [[Globals alloc]init];
    }
    return global;
}

@end
```

Comment: I know in a previous question (on the same subject) I suggested that you create a separate `XMLParser` class to perform this work, however you don't appear to understand how class instances work.  It makes no sense to have an instance of `XMLParser` instantiating yet another instance of its own class.  I think you need to step-back and take more time learning the basics of object-oriented programming.  I will vote to close this question as I don't believe you will understand any answer you are given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code for you, but as @trojanfoe has suggested please give yourself some time to learn some basic stuff.

```
- (IBAction)removeDuplicates:(id)sender
{
    //Below line will give you array of names directly from your array
    NSArray *names = [[[Globals globalBinding]globalArr] valueForKeyPath:@"firstname"];
    NSLog(@"Before removing Duplicate->%@",names);

    //Below method will clean remove all duplicate objects and you can create your string again
    NSArray *cleanedArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:names] allObjects];
    NSLog(@"After removing Duplicate->%@",cleanedArray);

    //String without duplicate to show in other textview
    NSString *strwithoutduplicate = [cleanedArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n "];    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is kind of working. Now if I wanted to remove other stuff from the profile aswel how would I do that? See edit above, that is how I display the profiles. since NSArray *cleanedArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:removeFirstNames] allObjects]; only takes removeFirstNames I am not able to remove last names etc

Comment: You should post another question for that, give a link here will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

```
1. Use NSSet. NSSet only gives unique objects from array.

    NSArray *arrayWithUniqueObjects = [[NSSet setWithArray:arrayWithDuplicateObjects] allObjects];

2. a) Take other array b) add objects from first array c) check if it is already added.

    NSMutableArray *firstArray = array with duplicate objects..;
    NSMutableArray *secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString* string in firstArray ) {
         if(![secondArray containsObject:string]) {
            [secondArray addObject:string];
         }
    }

// make string from objects of output array
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I use NSArray *arrayWithUniqueObjects = [[NSSet setWithArray:arrayWithDuplicateObjects] allObjects]; I can only remove duplicate firstNames, is there a way to make setWithArray hold more than one array? say if I wanted to pass the lastname array aswell? Check the edit on the answer above I have added some code. Thanks